# Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: gap -- Chain freezer table opened

Tags: go-ethereum

I started to get following error: `Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: gap (#3697270) in the chain between ancients and leveldb`. What may be the cause of this error?

- I was able to fix it by syncing my chain from scratch.

---

(`geth version: 1.9.13-unstable`)
// Please see the debug log with the highest verbostiy:

```
$ sudo geth --syncmode fast --cache=1024 --shh --datadir /private --port 3000 \
            --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain="*" \
            --networkid 12345 --rpcapi admin,eth,net,web3,debug,personal,shh \
            --targetgaslimit '10000000' --gasprice "18000000000" \
            --allow-insecure-unlock --verbosity 5
DEBUG[08-09|18:48:48.751] Sanitizing Go's GC trigger               percent=100
INFO [08-09|18:48:48.751] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [08-09|18:48:48.751] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
DEBUG[08-09|18:48:48.751] FS scan times                            list=25.366µs set=2.999µs diff=1.612µs
TRACE[08-09|18:48:48.751] Handled keystore changes                 time=45.406µs
TRACE[08-09|18:48:48.751] Started watching keystore folder         path=/private/keystore
INFO [08-09|18:48:48.752] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.9.13-unstable-0e6ea919/linux-amd64/go1.13.1
INFO [08-09|18:48:48.752] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=256.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [08-09|18:48:48.752] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/private/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=524288
DEBUG[08-09|18:48:48.837] Chain freezer table opened               database=/private/geth/chaindata/ancient table=bodies items=3697270 size=23.61MiB
DEBUG[08-09|18:48:48.838] Chain freezer table opened               database=/private/geth/chaindata/ancient table=receipts items=3697270 size=11.91MiB
DEBUG[08-09|18:48:48.838] Chain freezer table opened               database=/private/geth/chaindata/ancient table=diffs    items=3697270 size=14.07MiB
DEBUG[08-09|18:48:48.838] Chain freezer table opened               database=/private/geth/chaindata/ancient table=headers  items=3697270 size=1.05GiB
DEBUG[08-09|18:48:48.839] Chain freezer table opened               database=/private/geth/chaindata/ancient table=hashes   items=3697270 size=112.83MiB
INFO [08-09|18:48:48.839] Opened ancient database                  database=/private/geth/chaindata/ancient
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: gap (#3697270) in the chain between ancients and leveldb
```